# Построение линий уровня (изолиний)

Tags: графика, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток. Задача такая: на сетке значений построить линии уровней. Причем сетка координаты Y точек заданы не всегда через один и тот же шаг. Может у кого есть готовые алгоритмы, или библиотеки какие существуют? Или хотя бы ссылочку на хорошую литературу, а то я ничего толкового так и не смог найти. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел наиболее подходящий, на мой взгляд, алгоритм. Описан в работе А.В. Переберина "Построение изолиний с автоматическим масштабированием". Может кому-нибудь пригодится. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Answer (score 2):

на Java создал проект для изолинии, вход данные координаты со значением(double X, double Y, Integer VALUE). В проекте есть тесты. По началу построится Триангуляция Делоне, По ним и строится линии с одинаковым значением. Есть и дополнительные методы(уменьшение размера и умножение количеств треугольников для гладкости и ровности, аппроксимация, получение полигонов для карты). Очень быстрая. Теперь нужно добавить алгоритм построения изолинии при учете линии разлома(fault lines, break lines).[image: полигоны]

Comment: у меня репутации мало, по этому ссылку не мог добавить в ответ. Буду рад сотрудничестве. https://bitbucket.org/temnur/isoline/src

Comment: добавил ссылку на примеров  https://bitbucket.org/temnur/isoline/wiki/Home

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вопрос давно утратил свою актуальность, но будет интересно посмотреть на реализацию

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите алгоритм [Marching squares](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

Comment: На сколько я понял, этот алгоритм предназначен для регулярной сетки, а у меня она не регулярная. Попробую конечно, но неужели ни у кого нет готовых решений. Просто не хочется изобретать велосипед.